# Getting an element from Carbon class object

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In Laravel, when I was trying to print the value from the column `created_at`", I discovered that the value from this column is sent from the database as an instance of the class - `Illuminate\Support\Carbon`. After that, I am trying to print each element of this object, for example:

```
{
  "date":"2018-09-12 11:00:00.000000",
  "timezone_type":3,
  "timezone":"UTC"
}
```

I want to print "date". When I write the following:

```
$user = User::get(); // everything for every user
$first = $user[0]; // first user
$created = $user[0]['created_at']; // object of this Carbon class
$date = $created[0]; // or $created['date'])` date specifically
```

An error occurs:

> Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Carbon as array.

I can not find the reason for this. Any solution?

Comment: Sidenote: logic error; you define `$first` as `$user[0]`, but then don't ever use `$first`, instead referencing `$user[0]...` again.

Comment: user is an object not an array. So you can access user object like this
$user->created_at

Comment: @TimLewis yes, thank you for that.

Comment: @Gurpalsingh yes, I can do this, but what if I want to get only date from this "created_at" object?

Comment: you can simply get the date by using
$user->created_at->created_at->format('m/d/Y')

Comment: Yes, it works using format('m/d/Y'). Helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel converts anything declared as a date into a Carbon *object* when it retrieves the model. You're attempting to use Array syntax on an Object.

Try `$user->created_at` or `$user->created_at->format('m/d/Y')`

You may also benefit from learning about Arrays and Objects and their differences in PHP.

Comment: That is what I do not get. First of all, why is my code working at this line $first = $user[0] when I use Array syntax on an Object and on the other hand, since {
  "date":"2018-09-12 11:00:00.000000",
  "timezone_type":3,
  "timezone":"UTC"
} is an Object, why I can not use this code: $created->date ?

Comment: `$user` is a `Collection`, which is a fancy wrapper for an array. `$user[0]` should work with no issue, but there are helper methods to do the same, like `$user->first()`. `$user[0]` is an `Object`, a single instance of the `User` model. `$user->name` and `$user["name"]` should both work, due to the way models present data. `$created` is an `Object`, or a single instance of `Carbon`. That one you **must** use object syntax (`$created-> ...`), but `->date` is not a valid getter. Use `->format("Y-m-d")` to output a representative string.